# wxToolBar changing device coordinates

Tags: user-interface, wxwidgets

Using the mouse I am drawing 2D shapes on the client area of a MDIChildFrame. Recently I have added a wxToolBar to the frame and when I now draw a shape on the client area it seems that the points have shifted by the size the toolbar. Imagine that with mouse I am clicking on (100,100) and drawing a line to (150,150); however, the line appears somewhere (75,75) to (125,125). By the way, wxMouseEvent GetPosition(); reports (100,100) to me.

Removing the toolbar fixes the problem however, I want to keep the toolbar for ease of tool selection.

I use the code:

```
m_ToolBar=new wxToolBar(this, wxID_ANY);
m_ToolBar->AddTool() //
m_ToolBar->Realize();
this->SetToolBar(m_ToolBar);
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use [wxWindow::GetClientAreaOrigin()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a8fd1c0fd88d63dfbf6fefb688b7fd19e) to manually offset the coordinates by the toolbar height but normally this shouldn't be necessary, and if this doesn't happen with a "normal" frame but only happens with `wxMDIChildFrame` it would be a bug in wxWidgets that should be [reported as usual](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket).

It's also recommended to not draw over `wxFrame` itself but rather put a `wxWindow` into it and draw on it. This should also take care of your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped! I realized that wxToolBar can be treated as a regular component. I have included a wxBoxSizer and wxPanel onto which I am drawing rather than directly to the frame. I added wxToolBar and wxPanel via wxBoxSizer which solved the problem.